# Post-apocalyptic movie featuring a boat, a waterfall, a blonde woman underwater, and a bald guy in a light-coloured shirt

Tags: story-identification, movie

I found this movie on a Chinese site by chance. Some sort of post-apocalyptic movie.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am not sure if guy in the videos is Vin Diesel. It looks like him, but not sure.

Comment: Looks like Scarlett Johansson on the first screen?

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi - It looks a lot less like her when you remove the widescreen effect; https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sj1O5.png

Comment: @Valorum actress is Emily Blunt =)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is ***[Jungle Cruise](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0870154/)*** (2021).

From IMDB:

> Based on Disneyland's theme park ride where a small riverboat takes a group of travelers through a jungle filled with dangerous animals and reptiles but with a supernatural element.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jungle_Cruise_(film)):

> *Jungle Cruise* is a 2021 American fantasy adventure film directed by Jaume Collet-Serra from a screenplay written by Glenn Ficarra, John Requa, and Michael Green. It is based on Walt Disney's eponymous theme park attraction. Produced by Walt Disney Pictures, the film stars Dwayne Johnson, Emily Blunt, Édgar Ramírez, Jack Whitehall, Jesse Plemons, and Paul Giamatti. It tells the alternate history of the captain of a small riverboat who takes a scientist and her brother through a jungle in search of the Tree of Life while competing against a German expedition and cursed conquistadors.

The lady is Emily Blunt. The bald guy is Dwayne "The Rock" Johnson. The screenshots in the question are from a scene which occurs at about 90 minutes into the runtime.

[This article](https://www.insider.com/jungle-cruise-dwayne-johnson-emily-blunt-underwater-scene-2021-8) talks about the filming of the scene in a little more detail, and you can view a video clip of the scene in question below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's it: https://www.insider.com/jungle-cruise-dwayne-johnson-emily-blunt-underwater-scene-2021-8

Comment: It's not sci-fi, but it definitely has fantasy elements. Has a similar feel to _The Mummy (1999)_, except that it's mostly set on and around the Amazon River, rather than in Egypt.